# DiscordSocketClient ошибка импорта

Tags: c#, discord-api

Мне выводит ошибку "Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "DiscordSocketClient" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку)."
Суть ошибки понимаю. Но не понимаю как решить, устанавливал старые версии, пытался писать разные импорты но ошибка не уходила. Есть идеи?

Код:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.Net.WebSockets;

namespace Zexy
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Task Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync();

        private DiscordSocketClient _client; // ошибка

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient(); // ошибка

            _client.Log += Log; // ошибка

            var token = "token";

            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);
            await _client.StartAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task Log(LogMessage msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В NuGet кроме Discord.Net надо было ещё установить Discord.Net.WebSocket. А иначе будут вылезать ошибки как у меня.

Comment: Не надо там ставить что либо отдельно, достаточно только `Discord.Net` и все, а он уже зависим от всех необходимых [пакетов](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG7PD.png), которые NuGet скачает за вас.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).